# Proxy to re-route web requests

Tags: asp.net, webserver, virtual-pc

When running an ASP.NET web application on a local development machine, e.g. http://devmachine:1234, I would like to connect to that machine from a virtual pc that uses different browsers. As far as I know the development webserver only serves traffic for the local machine.

Is there a program / proxy that I can run on my local development machine that will listen for incoming connections from the virtual pc's browser and redirect them to the development webserver on my local machine?

e.g. virtual pc browser connect via proxy to local pc port 8080, then passes it on to devmachine port 1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to avoid using Casini for all but the most trivial example or proof-of-concept sites for this reason.

You're better off using IIS-proper rather than Casini/ASP.NET web development server.

Create either a web site or a virtual directory in IIS with the physical path that's the same as your local development files.  This way you'll be able to connect from any machine via your IP address and the site will be consistently available via a known address rather than sporadically available (i.e. when you have Casini running) via a port that varies.

Comment: Visual Studio will even create the Virtual Directory in IIS for you.  Just go to the Web tab of the project properties and choose IIS and click the button.

Comment: I've tried this, but when converting the web app to run from IIS, I get an error when running the application: "Unable to start debugging on the web server. The type initializer for 'System.Net.DigestClient' threw an exception."

I need to debug from a different OS / browser combination

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem with your OS/Browser combination.  Have you tried googling that specific error message?

Comment: This might be useful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/9d30fcfd-c872-478c-817e-52e184eb5e55/

Comment: Been there and back :)
There's probably something else wrong. I'll keep on trying. Jut thought someone new of a program like I asked.

Thanks

Comment: There is a program: it's called IIS :)

Comment: I ended up having to uninstall and reinstall IIS to fix the error I have been getting. I would still like to know of a program as explained to view http traffic as well.

Comment: If you want to view HTTP traffic, try the Firebug plug-in for Firefox.  Alternatively have a look at Wireshark.